# При смене ориентации адаптер выдает ошибку что массив пустой

Tags: android, adapter, recyclerview

Код адаптера

```
 public class RVSelectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVSelectAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {
        ArrayList<itemList> list = new ArrayList<itemList>();
        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
        Context context;

        public RVSelectAdapter(ArrayList<itemList> list,ArrayList<String> paths,Context context)
        {
            this.list = list;
            this.context = context;
            this.paths = paths;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            CardView cv;
            CheckBox checkBox;
            ImageView open;
            LinearLayout remove;
            LinearLayout edit;
            LinearLayout upload;
            View view;
            RecyclerView recyclerView;
            LinearLayout linearLayoutDetails;
            boolean openBool;
            TextView textViewTag;

            ViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);

                cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                open = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.open);
                remove = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                edit = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
                upload = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.upload);
                recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                view = itemView;
                linearLayoutDetails = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardDetail);
                openBool = false;
                textViewTag = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTag);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_select_card, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position)
        {
            holder.checkBox.setText(list.get(position).nameList);

            switch (list.get(position).Tag)
            {
                case "orph":
                    holder.textViewTag.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.orph));
                    break;
                case "arif":
                    holder.textViewTag.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.arif));
                    break;
            }

            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

            RVQuestionAdapter adapter = new RVQuestionAdapter(list.get(position).itemQuestions, context);
            holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            holder.open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (holder.linearLayoutDetails.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    {
                        ExpandAndCollapce.expand(holder.linearLayoutDetails, 500);

                        ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 180);
                        rotation.setDuration(500);
                        rotation.start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ExpandAndCollapce.collapse(holder.linearLayoutDetails, 500);

                        ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0);
                        rotation.setDuration(500);
                        rotation.start();
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    boolean res = new SaveAndLoad(context).remove(paths.get(position));
                }
            });

            holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, AddElementActivity.class).putExtra("itemList", list.get(position))
                    .putExtra("path", paths.get(position)));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
        {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }

         int convertDpToPixels(float dp)
         {
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    dp,
                    resources.getDisplayMetrics()
            );
        }

        public static class RVQuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder>
        {
            ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions;
            Context context;

            public RVQuestionAdapter(ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions, Context context)
            {
                this.itemQuestions = itemQuestions;
                this.context = context;
            }

            public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            {
                CardView cv;
                TextView textViewAnswer;
                TextView textViewEvaluation;

                ViewHolder(View itemView)
                {
                    super(itemView);

                    cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                    textViewAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswer);
                    textViewEvaluation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEvaluation);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public RVQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_select_answer, parent, false);
                ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

                return vh;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                holder.textViewAnswer.setText(itemQuestions.get(position).question);
                holder.textViewEvaluation.setText(new GetEvaluation(itemQuestions.get(position), context.getResources()).Text());
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount()
            {
                return itemQuestions.size();
            }
        }
    }
```

Лог ошибки

```
08-02 18:16:28.722 26306-26306/ru.landmarkstd.educt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: ru.landmarkstd.educt, PID: 26306
                                                                      Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle}
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at ru.landmarkstd.educt.Adapters.RVSelectAdapter.getItemCount(RVSelectAdapter.java:152)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3170)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2782)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:208)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:669)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:89)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1319)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:734)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1079)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2899)
                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1224)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCal
```

Comment: поскольку в `list` записывается значение параметра конструктора, очевидно конструктор вызывается с `null`, проблема не в адаптере, а в коде, где он создается.

Comment: Покажите код, где вы используете адаптер

Comment: Возможно вам поможет офф.документация https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Проблема в том, что при повороте устройства , Activity - пересоздаеться